# How to update values in a defaultdict depending on other keys

Tags: python

After a lengthy operation I get a defaultdict like the following:

```
l = defaultdict(list)
l = [('S', ['(', 'Num']), ('Num',['Sign', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Op', ['+', '-', '*', '/']), ('Sign', ['-'])]
print(l)
```

How can I now update all values for each key if they have values from another key?

Expected result:

Step 1:

```
l_new = [('S', ['(', 'Sign', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Num',['-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Op', ['+', '-', '*', '/']), ('Sign', ['-'])]
print(l)
```

Step 2:

```
l_new = [('S', ['(', '-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Num',['-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Op', ['+', '-', '*', '/']), ('Sign', ['-'])]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a one-liner like so:

```
l = dict([('S', ['(', 'Num']), ('Num',['Sign', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Op', ['+', '-', '*', '/']), ('Sign', ['-'])])
l_new = {
    k: [val for subl in (l.get(el, [el]) for el in v) for val in subl]
    for k, v in l.items()
}
print(l_new)
# {'S': ['(', 'Sign', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'],
#  'Num': ['-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'],
#  'Op': ['+', '-', '*', '/'],
#  'Sign': ['-']}
```

If you need to repeat the operation more than once, then just run it again. (Reassign to `l` and compute another `l_new`.)

Comment: What a brilliant solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
l = [('S', ['(', 'Num']), ('Num',['Sign', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Op', ['+', '-', '*', '/']), ('Sign', ['-'])]
l_d = dict(l) #convert l to a dictionary for faster lookup
def get_keys(d, c = []):
   if d not in l_d:
       yield d
   elif d not in c:
       yield from [i for k in l_d[d] for i in get_keys(k, c+[d])]

r = [(a, [j for k in b for j in get_keys(k)]) for a, b in l]
```

Output:

```
[('S', ['(', '-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Num', ['-', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']), ('Op', ['+', '-', '*', '/']), ('Sign', ['-'])]
```

With recursion, you do not need to manually run a single comprehension multiple times to replace key tokens in value lists of `l`, as it will continue to traverse `l`, replacing the key tokens with their subsequent non-key tokens.